# C short writing way of code

Tags: c, if-statement

My code is :

```
  if(nemrh<=305){  nemf=75; }
      if(305<nemrh<=325){ nemcarpan=0.05; nemkalan=nemrh-305; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=76+nemaratop; }
      if(325<nemrh<=350){ nemcarpan=0.04; nemkalan=nemrh-325; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=77+nemaratop; }
      if(350<nemrh<=370){ nemcarpan=0.05; nemkalan=nemrh-350; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=78+nemaratop; }
      if(370<nemrh<=393){ nemcarpan=0.0435; nemkalan=nemrh-370; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=79+nemaratop; }
      if(393<nemrh<=415){ nemcarpan=0.0454; nemkalan=nemrh-393; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=80+nemaratop; }
      if(415<nemrh<=440){ nemcarpan=0.04; nemkalan=nemrh-415; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=81+nemaratop; }
      if(440<nemrh<=465){ nemcarpan=0.04; nemkalan=nemrh-440; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=82+nemaratop; }
      if(465<nemrh<=490){ nemcarpan=0.04; nemkalan=nemrh-465; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=83+nemaratop; }
      if(490<nemrh<=515){ nemcarpan=0.04; nemkalan=nemrh-490; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=84+nemaratop; }
      if(515<nemrh<=540){ nemcarpan=0.04; nemkalan=nemrh-515; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=85+nemaratop; }
      if(540<nemrh<=563){ nemcarpan=0.0435; nemkalan=nemrh-540; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=86+nemaratop; }
      if(563<nemrh<=592){ nemcarpan=0.0344; nemkalan=nemrh-563; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=87+nemaratop; }
      if(592<nemrh<=620){ nemcarpan=0.0357; nemkalan=nemrh-592; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=88+nemaratop; }
      if(620<nemrh<=648){ nemcarpan=0.0357; nemkalan=nemrh-620; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=89+nemaratop; }
      if(648<nemrh<=678){ nemcarpan=0.0333; nemkalan=nemrh-648; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=90+nemaratop; }
      if(678<nemrh<=705){ nemcarpan=0.037; nemkalan=nemrh-678; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=91+nemaratop; }
      if(705<nemrh<=735){ nemcarpan=0.03333; nemkalan=nemrh-705; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=92+nemaratop; }
      if(735<nemrh<=766){ nemcarpan=0.0322; nemkalan=nemrh-735; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=93+nemaratop; }
      if(766<nemrh<=797){ nemcarpan=0.0322; nemkalan=nemrh-766; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=94+nemaratop; }
      if(797<nemrh<=830){ nemcarpan=0.0303; nemkalan=nemrh-797; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=95+nemaratop; }
      if(830<nemrh<=860){ nemcarpan=0.0333; nemkalan=nemrh-830; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=96+nemaratop; }
      if(860<nemrh<=894){ nemcarpan=0.0294; nemkalan=nemrh-860; nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan; nemf=97+nemaratop; }
```

How can I write this code that short way? I want to right it short version. Can anybody show me?

Comment: in C, `if (a < b <= c)` does not do what you think.

Comment: Please note that "nemaratop=nemkalan*nemcarpan;" statement is common for all(except the first if). So, it can be written as a single statement :)

Comment: change each `if` after the first one to `else if (nemrh <= value)`. It's sufficient. You can put numeric values in arrays and use a loop to check conditions. You will use more memory, but only write the inside of `ifs` once.

Comment: @TryinHard: Not so easy. It has data dependencies with previous assignments undef `if`. And next assignments under `if` depend on it. This is why it is written inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int arr1[] = {305, 325, 350, ..., 860, 894};
double arr2[] = {0.0, 0.05, 0.04, ..., 0.0333, 0.0294};
int arr3[] = {0, 305, 325, ..., 830, 860};
size_t i = 0;

if(nemrh <= 305} {  nemf=75; }
for(i = 1; i < sizeof arr1 / sizeof arr1[0]; ++i) {
   if(arr1[i-1] < nemrh && nemrh <= arr1[i]) { /* Hoping this is what you want */
     nemcarpan = arr2[i];
     nemkalan = nemrh - arr3[i];
     nemaratop = nemkalan * nemcarpan;
     nemf = 75 + i + nemaratop;
   }
}
```

You should rename `arr1` and `arr2` to something clearer. From the comment of [prajmus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716609/c-short-writing-way-of-code/31717028?noredirect=1#comment51371338_31717028), if nemrh is guaranteed to not modify even later, you can lean your code even more as:

```
int arr1[] = {305, 325, 350, ..., 860, 894};
double arr2[] = {0.0, 0.05, 0.04, ..., 0.0333, 0.0294};
int arr3[] = {0, 305, 325, ..., 830, 860};
size_t i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < sizeof arr1 / sizeof arr1[0]; ++i) {
   if(nemrh <= arr1[i]) {
     nemcarpan = arr2[i];
     nemkalan = nemrh - arr3[i];
     nemaratop = nemkalan * nemcarpan;
     nemf = (i == 0) ? 75 : 75 + i + nemaratop;
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think  you just do `if (nemrh <= arr1[i])`, add a `break` inside and put `for` in and `else` statement ?

Comment: @prajmus Looking at just small code snippet I did not rule out that nerh might be modified later. (There is no `else` in the code and bound check is on both side). If nemrh does not change, I would prefer to add both the suggestions from you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by `305<nemrh<=325` you meant `305 < nemrh && nemrh <= 325`

```
#define BASE 75

const struct 
{
  int a;
  double b;
} NEMRH_ARRGH[] = 
{
   { 305, 0.05 }, { 325, 0.04 }, { 350, 0.05 }, { 370, 0.0435 }, { 393, 0.0454 },
   { 415, 0.04 }, { 440, 0.04 }, { 465, 0.04 }, { 490, 0.04 }, { 515, 0.04 },
   { 540, 0.0435 }, { 563, 0.0344 }, { 592, 0.0357 }, { 620, 0.0357 }, { 648, 0.0333 },
   { 678, 0.037 }, { 705, 0.03333 }, { 735, 0.0322 }, { 766, 0.0322 }, { 797, 0.0303 },
   { 830, 0.0333 }, { 860, 0.0294 }
};

if (nemrh <= 305) 
  nemf = BASE;
  // But what about 'nemkalan' and co?
else if (nemrh > 894)
  ; // Do nothing? Really?
else
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof NEMRH_ARRGH / sizeof *NEMRH_ARRGH; ++i)
    if (nemrh > NEMRH_ARRGH[i].a) 
    {
      nemcarpan = NEMRH_ARRGH[i].b;
      nemkalan = nemrh - NEMRH_ARRGH[i].a;
      nemaratop = nemkalan * nemcarpan;
      nemf = BASE + 1 + i + nemaratop;
      break;
    }
```

Comment: The last assignment should probably be `nemf = HARRTHG_BASE + i + nemaratop;` and the `if` block should be terminated with `break;`